# Android bitmap tileModeY="repeat" with gravity="fill_horizontal" creates ugly edge

Tags: android, bitmap, repeat, tile, gravity

I want to create vertically repeating background for whole app that is adjusted to width of phone.

My bitmap is:

> resources/drawable/repeating_bitmap.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/app_bg_003_phone"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:tileModeY="repeat" />
```

My style is:

> resources/values/style.xml

```xml
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/repeating_bitmap</item>
  </style>
```

And my problem is here: [image: background with weird edge]

As you can see, instead of whole image only the edge is stretched, Weird.

How can i achieve horizontally stretched and vertically repeated background?
I have used proper flags on bitmap... (*android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:tileModeY="repeat"*)

If this could help this im attaching original image that im repeating (mdpi)

[image: image that im repeating]

I want to use repeating bitmap to save up on memory. Also this is only jpeg pattern that is available for me at the moment.

**Update**

Now i know why only edge is streched: From documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable

> "Gravity is ignored when the tile mode is enabled. Default value is "disabled"."

That means when i got tileModeY="repeat", then tileModeX by default as i enabled tile mode overall, must be tileModeX="clamp" which is:

> "clamp Replicates the edge color."

Any ideas how i can use tileMode and gravity at the same time? I tried to insert this bitmap into another view where gravity would be "fill_horizontal". Sadly without success.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. When I enable tileModeY the gravity is pretty much ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty fancy way of achieving this:

1. Remove the tileMode attribute from the "bitmap"
2. Create a "layer-list" root tag in the XML
3. Add an "item" tag around the "bitmap" with top and height attributes (set the height to that of the image)
4. Copy&paste this "item" as many times as you think you need it to fill the display
5. Enter the proper top value for each of the "item" tags

Here is an example where the image for the background is 116 pixel high. Therefore each of the following  tags has a top value increased by this height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="0dp" android:height="116dp">
        <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="116dp" android:height="116dp">
        <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="232dp" android:height="116dp">
        <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="348dp" android:height="116dp">
        <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="464dp" android:height="116dp">
        <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="580dp" android:height="116dp">
        <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```